# Select query WHERE clause - Exclude specific records

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I have a simple usp (basically a Select query). In the WHERE clause I need to exclude a specific value ([Instrument_Classification] of 'MXXOIS') that have a [Price_Currency] in ('CNY', 'BRL', 'CLP', 'THB'). All other [Instrument_Classification] of 'MXXOIS' that have [Price_Currency] of currencies other than the 4 noted above must be included. There are however hundreds of records with a [Instrument_Classification] of NULL, which must be included. The query looks as follows:

```
SELECT [Instrument_Classification], [Report_Status], [Price_Currency],
        [Transaction_Reference_Number], [Venue_Transaction_ID], [Executing_Entity_ID],
        [Date Received]
FROM [Transactions].[dbo].[TradeMessage]
WHERE  [Date Received] between '2022-10-27 00:00:00' and '2022-10-27 23:59:59'
AND ([Instrument_Classification] <> 'MXXOIS' 
        and [Price_Currency] in ('CNY', 'BRL', 'CLP', 'THB') 
        or [Instrument_Classification] is NULL
    )
```

The query returns all `[Instrument_Classification]` records with NULL values correctly but excludes all records with `[Instrument_Classification} of MXXOIS` plus also excludes all other records with `[Instrument_Classification} other than 'MXXOIS` e.g. code FFICSX'

The query should only exclude `[Instrument_Classification} of MXXOIS` with a `[Price_Currency] in ('CNY', 'BRL', 'CLP', 'THB')`.

Any `MXXOIS` record with a `[Price_Currency]` other than the 4 mentioned should be included.

My testing also, at some point, caused `[Instrument_Classification]` records with NULL with a `[Price_Currency] in ('CNY', 'BRL', 'CLP', 'THB')` to be excluded.

This is not correct as the only records to be excluded is `[Instrument_Classification}` of MXXOIS with a `[Price_Currency] in ('CNY', 'BRL', 'CLP', 'THB')`

Anyone able to help on my WHERE clause please?

Comment: Are you sure thats MySQL, looks more like SQLServer

Comment: Separate the items in the where clause. Put the two items in the and in its own parenthesis. Like ([Instrument_Classification] <> 'MXXOIS' and [Price_Currency] in ('CNY', 'BRL', 'CLP', 'THB'))
or [Instrument_Classification] is NULL

Comment: When mixing AND and OR in a where clause alway bracket then so the right result is enforced.

Comment: It really does help if you know which database you are using :)

Answer (score 1):

This first reads like a precedence issue. `OR` has lower priority than `AND`, so you need to be explicit about the expected order of operations when mixing both ; you do this by wrapping the predicates in parentheses.

So this:

```
[Instrument_Classification] <> 'MXXOIS' 
and [Price_Currency] in ('CNY', 'BRL', 'CLP', 'THB') 
or [Instrument_Classification] is NULL
```

Should be written :

```
(
    [Instrument_Classification] <> 'MXXOIS' 
    and [Price_Currency] in ('CNY', 'BRL', 'CLP', 'THB') 
)        
or [Instrument_Classification] is NULL
```

---

But since you said...

> I need to exclude a specific value ([Instrument_Classification] of 'MXXOIS') that have a [Price_Currency] in ('CNY', 'BRL', 'CLP')

I don't think the above condition does exactly what you want. Typically, your query excludes classifications MXXOIS, regardless of the currency.

I would suggest:

```
not (
    [Instrument_Classification] = 'MXXOIS' 
    and [Price_Currency] in ('CNY', 'BRL', 'CLP', 'THB') 
)        
or [Instrument_Classification] is NULL
```

Or we can use `OR`s:

```
[Instrument_Classification] <> 'MXXOIS' 
or [Price_Currency] <> ('CNY', 'BRL', 'CLP', 'THB') 
or [Instrument_Classification] is NULL
```